# The package installation failed in sandbox but successfully installed in production org.why.?

Tags: apex, managed-package, scheduled-apex, postinstall

I am trying to install managed package in sandbox org but it is not being installed and giving following error:

Problem:
1.  Unexpected Error
The package installation failed. Please provide the following information to the publisher:

Organization Name: **************

Organization ID: **********Gnf

Package: Test Management

Version: 5.5

**Error Message: The post install script failed.**

The same package is being successfully installed in production org.My post install script is 'without sharing'.Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like maybe your post installation action is relying some org data/metadata.

Comment: The problem is within your post install script. please share your code and we can have a look...

Comment: Have you figured out this by now? if So can you share please. Thanks.